# How to let bash script knows if the open terminal is closed or not

Tags: 12.04, bash, gnome-terminal

I want to write piece of bash script that open a gnome-terminal tab and execute some commands in it after finishing execution terminal will close , i would like the make bash recognize if this terminal is closed or still open cause i will make some action if it has been closed and make my script waits if it is still opened

can anyone help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run `gnome-terminal` disabling the factory mode. This will prevent it from starting a terminal connected to an existing terminal, so that the command does not return immediately:

```
gnome-terminal --disable-factory
echo Done. # Will only run after the terminal opened above has been closed
```

From [`man gnome-terminal`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html):

```
--disable-factory
             Do not register with the activation name server, do  not  re-
             use an active terminal.
```

---

Most applications start a new process independent of any previously running processes when run. Some applications (like Firefox, GNOME Terminal, etc.) do not open a completely new process when run. They start a session tied to an existing process. So if you have a Firefox window open, and you run:

```
firefox
```

in a terminal, it will open a new window connected to the existing process and return immediately. In the case of GNOME Terminal, you can disable this behaviour using the above option. With `--disable-factory`, the new window opened is tied to this command, so the command waits until the window is closed.

Comment: it works fine and great but i don't understand how actually , i will appreciate it so much if u explain more pls :)

Comment: @AhmedZainElDein updated with an explanation.

Comment: When u say "so the command waits until the window is closed."
,so if i wrote those command that will be execute in terminal in for loop that means like this :

`for (( ; ; ))
do
gnome-terminal -- disable-factory line 1

gnome-terminal -- disable-factory line 2
done`
 he will not execute line line2 until line1 is closed?

Comment: @AhmedZainElDein yes, the second gnome-terminal will not be executed until the first is ended.